# Есть ли какой то универсальный форматировщик для css

Tags: css

Пример.
Есть у меня класс **css**,
Как я могу с помощью расширения добавить максимальную совсместимость.
Тоесть
было -->

```css
.element {
  background: rgb(204,0,255);
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(204,0,255,1) 11%, rgba(98,0,255,1) 86%);
}
```

стало -->

```css
element {
  background: rgb(204,0,255);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(204,0,255,1) 11%, rgba(98,0,255,1) 86%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(204,0,255,1) 11%, rgba(98,0,255,1) 86%);
  background: linear-gradient(160deg, rgba(204,0,255,1) 11%, rgba(98,0,255,1) 86%);
}
```

Есть ли какие нибудь такие расширения для **vscode**?

Comment: Обычно такое делают не в редакторе, а в процессе сборки фронтенда с помощью плагинов вроде [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer)

Comment: Тем не менее, autoprefixer для vscode тоже почему-то существует https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mrmlnc.vscode-autoprefixer